# Measuring voltage

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

Recently I was playing around with this circuit simulation, and I found that if I had a circuit with just a lightbulb and cell, then If I were to measure the voltage between the bulb and cell it gives me 0. But when I measure the voltage between both ends of the bulb it gives me the battery voltage. If the voltage was 0 for the first one, then how do electrons even move if there is no potential difference? I'm quite confused.

Comment: The simulation assumes a superconducting wire and thus the potential  difference across it is often ignored. Due to the idealisation that E=0, which is not true if there is a battery connected. It is just an abstraction. Which isn't what actually happens in superconducting wires, but the PD across them compared to the bulb is miniscule so is ignored. Conceptually, the simulation is entirely wrong.

Comment: @jensenpaull That's a bit harsh. Conceptually, the simulation captures the subset of the physics it's meant to capture. The drift current in the wire is not in that subset. But that, of course, is why students should do more with real wires and resistors before attempting simulations and mathematical abstraction.

Comment: Except it has led OP to think that even in superconducting wires, the pd across them is zero. Which is wrong

Comment: @jensenpaull simulators aren't (for the most part)  designed to teach students. For example, they also don't capture self heating behavior, arcing due to over voltage, interference due to proximity with other circuits, manufacturing variation between components, etc.

Answer (score 1):

> If the voltage was 0 for the first one, then how do electrons even move if there is no potential difference?

For some reason this is a very common misconception. Electrons do not require a potential difference to move. They can and do move without a potential difference or even against a potential difference.

The potential difference across a resistor is proportional to the current through it. But that is not a general law of physics. Ohm’s law specifically applies to resistors, not to other materials or devices, such as batteries, capacitors, inductors, and superconductors. For all of those other devices current can flow without or even against a potential difference.

Comment: Common wire materials are well modeled as ohmic. Ohm's law applies to them.

Comment: It is a simulation, not a wire. In the simulation there is no voltage and there is no law of physics that requires there to be one. I often work with superconducting wires

Comment: Yes, it's a simulation. That's the real reason. In the real world, there would be a voltage between the ends of the wire. Ohm's law does not specifically apply to resistors: things that aren't officially resistors sometimes still follow Ohm's law. Be real: have you ever used superconducting wire to connect a cell to a light bulb?

Comment: Yes, be real. The student has a real conceptual challenge and you are ignoring it. That the simulation is an approximation is a triviality, and that a real voltmeter has limited sensitivity is another. The conceptual mistake that the student is making is the common but incorrect idea that charges only move down a potential gradient. That is false in batteries, capacitors, inductors, and superconductors. You really do the student a disservice by ignoring their real conceptual challenge

Comment: I think that bringing up exotica like superconductors does nothing to help with the conceptual challenge here. When Ohm's law suffices, which it does here, it's a really good place for students to start. The real circuit uses an ohmic wire. The simulation isn't real.

Comment: I disagree. The “exotica” like superconductors, capacitors, batteries, and inductors directly address the student’s conceptual challenge by pointing out that their mental rule often fails. Talking about simulations and voltmeter precision does not address the conceptual challenge they are facing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137666/discussion-between-john-doty-and-dale).

Comment: No thank you, John. I see no value in taking this to chat.

Comment: Batteries aren't hard to understand as "black boxes", and that does not seem to be a problem here. Inductors and capacitors are not involved here, and in any case, generalizing Ohm's law to impedance is a fine path into understanding them.
But the real problem is that physics is increasingly taught as abstract, all math and simulation. One consequence is the scandalous result of the Sadler social experiment, where students graduating from MIT (!) couldn't manage to make a circuit from a battery, a light bulb, and a wire.

Comment: Indeed, batteries are not hard to understand as black boxes, and this student even included one in their example. Which is why it is useful to point out to them that even batteries break Ohms law

Comment: The fact that there is a battery in the simulation means there is a voltage, no voltage is needed to maintain this current but there is still a voltage in this situation none the less. Although this simulation is an abstraction that uses E=0 when r=0, which isn't even true here. There wouldn't be a constant current in the wire in this situation, but obviously the simulation assumes there is. Which is wrong

Comment: The simulation isn’t the student’s conceptual problem. The student’s challenge is in their words “how do electrons even move if there is no potential difference”. In other words, they believe that a voltage is required for a current. This is a common misconception that stems from believing that Ohm’s law is universal. That is what we can and should address here. The simulation authors are not asking the question so focusing on the simulation misses helping the person who actually did ask the question

Comment: But in the real circuit, using ordinary hook-up wire, the electrons won't actually move without a potential difference. So, bringing up other cases just causes more confusion here. Premature generalization inhibits real learning.

Comment: The student already had generalized

Answer (score 1):

In a real circuit, with a sufficiently sensitive voltmeter, you can measure a small voltage between the ends of a wire carrying current in a circuit like this. But, the wire is made of a low resistance material (commonly copper), so the voltage required to drive the current is small. This is by design.

The simulator idealizes this to zero resistance, so in simulation there is no voltage required to drive the current.